# Highcharts draw shape (arrow) at the end of x and y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to draw shapes at the end of your Axis? (see image)

[image]

I have looked all over the documentation and couldn't really find anything about this specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want draw a arrow you can check the [general drawing demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/renderer) from Highcharts demos page.
There are using [Highcharts.SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) to render arrow, you can transform it to axis.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          xAxisLeft = chart.xAxis[0].left,
          xAxisHeight = chart.xAxis[0].height + chart.xAxis[0].top,
          rightArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 0, 'L', 95, 5, 'M', 100, 0, 'L', 95, -5];

        if (chart.myPath) {
          chart.myPath.destroy();
        }

        chart.myPath = chart.renderer.path(rightArrow)
          .attr({
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: '#ccd6eb',
            fill: 'none'
          })
          .translate(95, 95)
          .add();
      }
    },
  },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2m573wr/